# Fading DIVs while preserving space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three DIVs in my HTML with the classes "blockOne", "blockTwo", and "blockThree".

I would like them to start out invisible to the user and fade in as the user scrolls down the page. Currently, I have already set them to have an opacity of 0 like so (in the CSS):

```
.blockOne {
opacity: 0; 
}

.blockTwo {
opacity: 0; 
}

.blockThree {
opacity: 0; 
}
```

I then have a the following script:-

```
    $(document).scroll(function(){
var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop(),
    threeBoxesOffset = $(".content").offset().top - 25;

if (docScroll >= threeBoxesOffset) {

    $(".blockOne").fadeTo(1000, 1)
    $(".blockTwo").fadeTo(1500, 1)
    $(".blockThree").fadeTo(2000, 1)

} else {

    $(".blockOne").fadeTo(500, 0)
    $(".blockTwo").fadeTo(1000, 0)
    $(".blockThree").fadeTo(1500, 0)

}
});
```

The result is the DIVs being invisible to the user at the start, which is correct, but as the user scrolls down to the point where they start to become visible, they don't immediately start fading in and instead take some time before doing so.

I guess the animation is being queued somehow as the user scrolls down and am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Why you are setting the opacity with jquery.Just use CSS for initial styles

Comment: Edited to use CSS instead, thanks!

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Check my answer again, adjusted to fit your edits

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahSD3/

Comment: @ReignOfComputer I will post the solution in 5 min

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to it :O

Comment: Urk, not sure what's wrong T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threeBoxesOffset` always contains a negative value because of`$(".content").offset().top - 25`.Therefore in your script the condition `if (docScroll >= threeBoxesOffset)` is always true and shows the content immediately on scroll.I have now made a solution for it:

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahSD3/9/)(<kbd>updated</kbd>) / Watch [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/ahSD3/9/show/)

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var threeBoxesOffset = $(".content").offset().top - 40;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        var check=docScroll+threeBoxesOffset;           
        $('#fxd').html('check : '+check);
        if (check>0) {
            $(".blockOne").stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
            $(".blockTwo").stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);
            $(".blockThree").stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},2000);
        } else {
            $(".blockOne").stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},500);
            $(".blockTwo").stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},1000);
            $(".blockThree").stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},1500);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( docScroll >= threeBoxesOffset ) {
    $('.blockOne').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('.blockTwo').fadeIn(500, function() {
            $('.blockThree').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
} else {
    $('.blockOne').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('.blockTwo').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.blockThree').fadeOut(500);
        });
    });
}
```

PS - at the end of your code you have an unmatched set closers:

```
}
})    // <-- not matched with anything above
});
```

Comment: Oopsie, I actually had this but I copied the code segment wrongly. Thanks, edited!

Comment: Still didn't work :(
Removed the unmatched set closers, they were for the document ready function I accidentally copied.